Keyboard doesn't work in wine under fvwm2 with FocusFollowsMouse
I'm running Debian 12 with fvwm2 window manager (version 2.7.0) configured for point-to-focus (FocusFollowsMouse) and a few XFCE utilities, such as xfce4-panel.
When I start wine notepad or wine explorer, keyboard input doesn't work; nothing happen when I type. Doing things with the mouse (selecting menu items, clicking around the filesystem in Explorer, etc.) seems to work fine, but I cannot enter text in Notepad or in the URL bar of File Explorer. In Notepad, choosing Edit then Paste from the menus does paste in the contents of X11 my clipboard selection.
This answer to a similar question might be related, but I'm not using a stacking window manager; fvwm is tiling.
Some further research shows that Wine works fine under Xfce's Window manager, xfwm4, and also works if I change fvwm2's focus policy to ClickToFocus or SloppyFocus. Going back to FocusFollowsMouse and looking more closely, I see that my title bar, which is highlighted when a window receives keyboard focus, does not highlight when I move the mouse over the Wine window (though the previous window my mouse was in does lose focus).
Examining the window properties of various windows, including a standard terminal, the pop-up window that shows me the properties, xclock and the Wine window, I see some differences:
window name           Focus Policy:     Input Field:        WM_TAKE_FOCUS:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
urxvt                 Passive           True                Absent
FvwmIdent             Passive           XwMHints missing    Absent
xclock                No Input          False               Absent
Untitled - Notepad    Globally Active   False               Present

Does anybody have any thoughts on what's wrong and how to fix this?

if you try a different de/wm does it work?

@killertofus Yes; it appears to be an issue with focus following the mouse. I've updated the question with considerably more information, and added x11 and fvwm tags.
